# Swipe Navigation from right to left from storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, swipe

Is it possible to make a right to left swipe in Xcode storyboard without coding? I managed to change the side of the finger's movement but the animation is still going from left to right.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yzDS.png)

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. What's the navigation that you are talking about? Do you have a UINavigationController?

Comment: Yes I have, I also have three UIViewControllers, I created swipe gesture recognizers and segues to go from ViewController1 to ViewController2 to ViewController3 and it works. Now I also want to do the same thing to go back, I created a swipe gesture recognizer and a segue to go from ViewController3 to ViewController2 and it works. I have set the swipe to right, so it works when I swipe from right to left but the animation still goes from left to right. I want to make it from right to left.

Comment: Are those view controllers embedded in navigation controller? Can you include a screenshot showing your view controllers (just edit your question)? ...a picture tells a 1000 words.

Comment: I just added the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible as per your configuration. The only and correct way to do it is to detect your desired action (in your case right to left swipe) and to dismiss or pop view controller programmatically.